# Need VB code commented to convert it to Java

Tags: vb.net, comments

I am a Java developer. I have the task of converting a VB class to Java.

Can some VB developer comment the following VB code so that I can write its Java equivalent?

```
Public Class RmaValidationCode
    ' Values for test type
    Public Const SOFTWARE_TEST_TYPE = 0
    Public Const FIRMWARE_TEST_TYPE = 1
    ' Values for test length
    Public Const SHORT_TEST_LENGTH = 0
    Public Const LONG_TEST_LENGTH = 1
    ' Values for test result
    Public Const PASS_TEST_RESULT = 0
    Public Const FAIL_TEST_RESULT = 1
    Public Const ABORT_TEST_RESULT = 2
    Public Const CAUTION_TEST_RESULT = 3
    ' GetRMAValidationCode function bit mapped return values
    Public Const RMA_VC_RET_PASS = 0
    Public Const RMA_VC_RET_NULL_PTR_PARAMETER = 1
    Public Const RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_STR_LENGTH = 2
    Public Const RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_SN_STRING = 4
    Public Const RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_TEST_TYPE = 8
    Public Const RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_TEST_LENGTH = 16
    Public Const RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_TEST_RESULT = 32

    Private Const RMA_LENGTH = 8

    Private rmaValidationCode As String

    ' This function will return the warranty validation code based on serial number, test type, 
    ' test result, test software and test length.
    ' Test type - Generic=0, DST=1
    ' Test result - Pass=0, FAIL=1
    ' Test Software - DOS=0, Windows=1
    ' Test Length - Short=0 Long=1
    Public Function GetRMAValidationCode(ByVal serialNumber As String, ByVal testType As Byte, _
        ByVal testResult As Byte, ByVal testSoftware As Byte, ByVal testLength As Byte)

        Dim returnValue As UInt32
        Dim tempRMACode As String
        Dim tempRMAEnumerator As CharEnumerator
        Dim temp8Bit As Byte

        returnValue = RMA_VC_RET_PASS
        temp8Bit = 0

        ' Make sure we were passed valid strings
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(serialNumber) OrElse _
           String.IsNullOrEmpty(rmaValidationCode) Then
            returnValue = returnValue Or RMA_VC_RET_NULL_PTR_PARAMETER
        End If

        ' Make sure our strings are big enough
        If serialNumber.Length < RMA_LENGTH OrElse _
           rmaValidationCode.Length < RMA_LENGTH Then
            returnValue = returnValue Or RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_STR_LENGTH
        End If

        ' Assure that valid test types were passed in
        If testType <> SOFTWARE_TEST_TYPE AndAlso _
           testType <> FIRMWARE_TEST_TYPE Then
            returnValue = returnValue Or RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_TEST_TYPE
        End If

        ' Assure that valid test lengths were passed in
        If testLength <> SHORT_TEST_LENGTH AndAlso _
           testLength <> LONG_TEST_LENGTH Then
            returnValue = returnValue Or RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_TEST_LENGTH
        End If

        ' Assure that valid test results were passed in
        If testResult <> PASS_TEST_RESULT AndAlso _
           testResult <> FAIL_TEST_RESULT AndAlso _
           testResult <> ABORT_TEST_RESULT AndAlso _
           testResult <> CAUTION_TEST_RESULT Then
            returnValue = returnValue Or RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_TEST_RESULT
        End If

        If returnValue = RMA_VC_RET_PASS Then
            ' Trim leading and trailing whitespace
            serialNumber.Trim()
            ' Check to see if the serialNumber string is long enough
            ' after whitespace is removed
            If serialNumber.Length < RMA_LENGTH Then
                Return RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_SN_STRING
            End If

            tempRMACode = serialNumber.ToLower()
            tempRMAEnumerator = tempRMACode.GetEnumerator()

            While (tempRMAEnumerator.MoveNext())
                If Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(tempRMAEnumerator.Current) Then
                    Return RMA_VC_RET_INVALID_SN_STRING
                End If
            End While

            ' Initialize the rmaValidationCode
            rmaValidationCode = ""

            ' Compute and save the first 6 bytes of RMA Validation Code
            temp8Bit = 0
            temp8Bit = Convert.ToByte(tempRMACode.ToCharArray().GetValue(0)) + Convert.ToByte((tempRMACode.ToCharArray()).GetValue(7))
            rmaValidationCode += String.Format("{0:X2}", temp8Bit)

            temp8Bit = 0
            temp8Bit = Convert.ToByte((tempRMACode.ToCharArray()).GetValue(1)) + Convert.ToByte((tempRMACode.ToCharArray()).GetValue(6))
            rmaValidationCode += String.Format("{0:X2}", temp8Bit)

            temp8Bit = 0
            temp8Bit = Convert.ToByte((tempRMACode.ToCharArray()).GetValue(2)) + Convert.ToByte((tempRMACode.ToCharArray()).GetValue(5))
            rmaValidationCode += String.Format("{0:X2}", temp8Bit)

            ' Byte 6 is the Test & Result byte.
            temp8Bit = 0
            temp8Bit = (testSoftware << 3) Or (testResult << 2) Or (testType << 1) Or testLength
            rmaValidationCode += String.Format("{0:X1}", temp8Bit)

            ' Compute the parity byte
            temp8Bit = 0
            Dim mychar As Char
            mychar = rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(3)

            If ((Convert.ToInt32(rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(3), 16) Mod 2) = 1) Then
                temp8Bit = temp8Bit Or (1 << 3)
            Else
                temp8Bit = temp8Bit Or (0 << 3)
            End If

            Dim value As Integer
            mychar = rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(2)
            value = System.Convert.ToInt32(mychar, 16)
            If ((Convert.ToInt32(rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(2), 16) Mod 2) = 1) Then
                temp8Bit = temp8Bit Or (1 << 2)
            Else
                temp8Bit = temp8Bit Or (0 << 2)
            End If

            mychar = rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(1)

            If ((Convert.ToInt32(rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(1), 16) Mod 2) = 1) Then
                temp8Bit = temp8Bit Or (1 << 1)
            Else
                temp8Bit = temp8Bit Or (0 << 1)
            End If

            mychar = rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(0)

            If ((Convert.ToInt32(rmaValidationCode.ToCharArray().GetValue(0), 16) Mod 2) = 1) Then
                temp8Bit = temp8Bit Or 1
            Else
                temp8Bit = temp8Bit Or 0
            End If
            rmaValidationCode += String.Format("{0:X1}", temp8Bit)
        End If

        Return rmaValidationCode
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        '    serialNumber = "                    "
        rmaValidationCode = "        "
        '  testType = 0
        'testLength = 0
        'testResult = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There are already a bunch of comments in the code that give you hints as to what the code does.  What lines are you stuck on?

Comment: It may help to accept an answer every once in a while, too.

Comment: Whining aside, anyone fancy editing this to bring it up to proper question standards?

Answer (score 4):

Actually that is pretty readable and straightforward code. You may want to take a look at [VB keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t%28VS.71%29.aspx) as well as the [AndAlso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx)/[OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) operators (those two sometimes confuse C-style language developers). The rest that's used are just plain old .NET class library methods. Nothing too fancy and you'll find plenty of documentation about those on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately you're not going to find anyone here that will comment the above code for free.**

Visual Basic syntax is *relatively simple* - it was designed as an entry level language. If you engage your mind and read over the **general key words** such as `AndAlso` `OrElse` `WhileNot` etc, you shouldn't have a massive issue commenting it *yourself.*

If you were further interested in the way the code works - the way I usually learn to understand X piece of code is to go **step - by - step** through it until I *finall*y get the gist of it.

**Try searching [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) for any keywords you don't fully understand.**